# Multiple Charts in PySide6 with changable Layout

Tags: python, qtcharts, pyside6

I want to create a 2D visualization tool in PySide6.
I have a `QGridLayout` I have a `QChartView` and in this a `QChart`.
Now I want to be able to arrange the Charts in with a `QSpinBox` so I can tell the charts how they should be lined up. (like 2 x 2 for 4 charts or maybe 4 x 1 for also 4 charts)

```
class Ui_Chart(QWidget):
    def __init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        self.ui.ChartsLayoutx = QSpinBox()
        self.ui.ChartsLayouty = QSpinBox()
        self.ui.ChartsLayoutx.valueChanged.connect(self.layoutxchange)
        self.ui.ChartsLayouty.valueChanged.connect(self.layoutychange)
        self.ui.ChartsLayoutx.setValue(self.xlayout)
        self.ui.ChartsLayouty.setValue(self.ylayout)
        self.ui.ChartsLayoutx.setMinimum(1)
        self.ui.ChartsLayouty.setMinimum(1)
...


    def DrawCharts(self, data = None):
        chart = CreateChart(self.data if data == None else data)
        self.ui.ChartsLayout.addWidget(chart)
        self.charts.append(chart)
        x = len(self.charts)/2 if (len(self.charts)/2).is_integer() else int((Decimal(len(self.charts))/2).to_integral_value(rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP))
        y = x
        self.layoutxchange(x)
        self.layoutychange(y)
        

    @Slot(None)
    def layoutxchange(self, arg):
        x=1
        y=1
        if len(self.charts) > self.ylayout*arg:
            return
        elif len(self.charts) == self.ylayout*arg:
            for i in range(len(self.charts)):
                x=0
                y=0
                if arg >= x:
                    self.ui.ChartsLayout.replaceWidget(self.ui.ChartsLayout.itemAtPosition(x,y).widget(), self.charts[i])

                    x+=1
                    y+=1
                else:
                    x=0
        else:
            for i in range(len(self.charts)):
                x=0
                y=0
                if arg >= y:
                    self.ui.ChartsLayout.replaceWidget(self.ui.ChartsLayout.itemAtPosition(x,y).widget(), self.charts[i])

                    x+=1
                    y+=1
                else:
                    x=0
        self.xlayout = x
        self.ylayout = y
        self.ui.ChartsLayoutx.setValue(self.xlayout)
        self.ui.ChartsLayouty.setValue(self.ylayout)


... And the same for layoutychange...
```

Can this even work or should I just not try it?

Comment: Let's say you initially have 4 QChartViews located at 2x2 but then select the spinboxes at 3x3, how should the QChartViews be relocated?

Comment: The spinboxes are not in the Layout, they should control the layout

Comment: My question was clear, let's say that the first spinbox has the value of 3 and the second the value of 5, so should 15 QChartViews be displayed?

Comment: Yes, but there would not be that much

Comment: I think this can work, you could try.